# How to hide a modal popup without backdrop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm triggering the following modal dialog from javascript:

```
$('#myModal').modal({
    show: true,
    backdrop: false
});
```

Result: the dialog shows up, but is not closed if I click outside of the popup.

When I set `backdrop: true`, the dialog is closed on outside click, *but* the full screen appears with a dimmed overlay.

How can I have a modal popup that does not change the `opacity` overlay, but still closes on outside click?

Comment: hey have you found a solution to this? Was my suggestion able to guide you in the right direction? Hope so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `background-color` to `.modal-backdrop` as such...

```
<style>
    .modal-backdrop {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
</style>

<!-- [...] -->

<script>
    // [...]
    $('#myModal').modal({
        show: true
    });
</script>
```

[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/pXOxXTNdi0Cxi8zIILCr?p=preview) - demo

Answer (score 0):

You can leave backdrop:false, and add your own click event to the page:

```
$('body').click(function(e){
   if ($('#myModal').is(e.target))
       $('#myModal').modal('hide') //or whatever your bootstrap uses to hide a modal
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'false', keyboard: false})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/obewgqc8/